# How to create custom PHP/Mysql page in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I'm currently assigned to create custom page in ExpressionEngine (because that's the old code). I'm not getting used to ExpressionEngine and CodeIgniter either. I do inspecting the structure of current code then I decide to put my script to the template so I just choose the template when I create new page in ExpressionEngine admin page.

The question is: How to put my custom PHP script to that template because I could not find one PHP script in other template before? or If my way is wrong, How to create custom PHP page in ExpressionEngine?

FYI: custom script is want to connect to other server DB and google map API.

Comment: Hi @Leo, try posting your question here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I did it. and still waiting for a solution. (panic) :(